# The answer to this riddle is another number

Tags: riddle

This is another one I created a long time ago, probably quite easy to the smart fellas here.

> This is a riddle, that much you must know
>   But what on earth is this passage supposed to show?
>   It seems that no question is being made clear
>   And yet an answer you have to give here
>   One, Four, Five, Two, Twelve, Twenty-Four
>   Submit the right number and you need think no more.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is

> Twenty

this is because

> Each number corresponds to a letter in each sentence.

Further Explanation:

> If you count letters in each sentence according to the 5th line, you will find that the first letter in the first sentence is T, the fourth letter of the second sentence is w, so on so forth.

Comment: Congrats BlueFire, that was quick.